# Spring 3.2 + Hibernate 4 OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm a Spring newbie trying my first app.  My hibernate gets closed before the view is rendered and having problems with lazy loaded properties (expected behavior).  I've added the OpenSessionInViewFilter to my web.xml and caused the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

Beforehand It was working fine with the default servlet context config I've had (can someone tell me why?).  So I've added the following:

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

The new error went away..but still getting a no session exception from hibernate

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.test.model.Store.categories, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I've put a debug message in one of my controllers and it seems that its being initialized 3 times.  Maybe I have more than one instance of hibernate session factory bean?  My controller methods are marked @Transactional and everything worked until I've attempted to leave the session open to make the lazy fields available for the view.

My full web.xml (with the new context addition, worked fine without it before I've added the hibernate filter):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" > 
    <display-name>
      Spring
    </display-name>
    <description>
     Spring Test
    </description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

   <filter>
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>      
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping> 

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>



  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/500</location>
  </error-page>
   <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/resources/pages/error.html</location>
  </error-page>



</web-app>
```

springapp-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.web.controllers,com.test.service.impl" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="username" value="spring"/>
    <property name="password" value="test"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath*:com/test/model/hbm/**/*.hbm.xml" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        hibernate.show_sql=true
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven />
  <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>


    <bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/templates/"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
      <property name="cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="prefix" value=""/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
      <property name="layoutUrl" value="index.vm" />

      <!-- if you want to use the Spring Velocity macros, set this property to true -->
      <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>

    </bean>

     <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="categoryDAO" class="com.test.dao.hibernate.HibernateCategoryDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="categoryService" class="com.test.service.Categories" scope="singleton">
        <property name="dao" ref="categoryDAO"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="storeDAO" class="com.test.dao.hibernate.HibernateStoreDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="storeService" class="com.test.service.Stores" scope="singleton">
        <property name="dao" ref="storeDAO"></property>
        <property name="categoryDao" ref="categoryDAO"></property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My controllers where initialized twice, the same config was used by the root ApplicationContext and by the FrameworkServlet.  I've had two contexts initialized.  I've created a config for the root context named springapp.xml and moved all my middle tier configuration there and left my web tier configuration in springapp-servlet.xml

My web.xml now looks like this and everything works fine:

```
      <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/springapp.xml
        </param-value>
        </context-param>

     <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

<filter>
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>      
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   </filter-mapping> 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>



      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Yeah it solved my problem too, searched for a while and hopefully found it. Works good on spring 4.0.4 :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem in my case it was just missing this line

in the application-context file.

The @Transactional annotation over a method was not taken into account.

Hope it will help someone

Comment: what line? please review your answer