# One Session Per Request Pattern with Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am starting a project with Spring MVC and Hibernate and I do not fully understand the best practices for data access.

After some research, I understand that we should use different layers (DAO layer, service layer) to separate the business logic from the actual database interactions.

However, I do not know how I can guarantee that only one hibernate session is generated for every one HTTP request.

**For example**: suppose I have a web-page for a restaurant that displays two menus: a deals-of-the-day menu and the chef's special dishes. Both menus are displayed on the same web-page.

I would imagine there would be two services:

**DealsOfDayService** - gets all dishes that are on deals of the day

**ChefSpecialsService** - gets all dishes on chef's specials list

However, when a user requests for this page. The controller would call both service methods to retrieve the needed data for the web-page. But each time a service method is called, a new hibernate session is created, used, and closed.

I am wondering how I can use only one hibernate session to obtain both lists, because opening a session for every service operation seems really expensive. (I guess I am asking if there is a way to chain service calls; as in the second service somehow uses the session created in the first service method, avoiding the need to create a new session).

If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to handle this problem, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use Spring Boot and just trust its transaction management. (Generally preferable to use the JPA personality on Hibernate in any case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) available in Spring Framework.
This will suit in your requirement. This filter extends [OncePerRequestFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) which will ensure Opening the hibernate session once per Http Request.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544670/spring-3-2-hibernate-4-opensessioninviewfilter) post will help you configuring the filter.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you very much :)